# BigQuery JSON Array extraction

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this JSON

```
    "type": "list",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "5bc7a3396fbc71aaa1f744e3",
            "type": "company",
            "url": "/companies/5bc7a3396fbc71aaa1f744e3"
        },
        {
            "id": "5b0aa0ac6e378450e980f89a",
            "type": "company",
            "url": "/companies/5b0aa0ac6e378450e980f89a"
        }
    ],
    "url": "/contacts/5802b14755309dc4d75d184d/companies",
    "total_count": 2,
    "has_more": false
}
```

I want to dynamically create columns as the number of the companies with their Ids, for example:

| company_0 | comapny_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 5bc7a3396fbc71aaa1f744e3 | 5b0aa0ac6e378450e980f89a |

Tried to use [BigQuery's JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) but I didn't get along with it.

Thank you.

Comment: did you have chance to search within SO? there are number of posts similar to this one that are answered already!

Comment: searched a lot but didn't find the same case as I have, objects inside an array with the same keys. can you please point me to a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(json) from (
  select json, json_extract_scalar(line, '$.id') company, offset
  from your_table t, unnest(json_extract_array(json, '$.data')) line with offset
  where json_extract_scalar(line, '$.type') = 'company'
)
pivot (any_value(company) company for offset in (0, 1))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]